# Moodle contacts and convsersation 3.2+

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, moodle, mustache

So, I have the next problem:
I try to create the new div `@type@` in

> /message/templates/message_area_contact.mustache

So the code looks like this:

```
 ... <div class="name">
        {{fullname}}   
       <div style="font-style: italic; font-weight: 100;">{{type}}</div>
        {{#showonlinestatus}}
            <span {{^isonline}}class="hidden"{{/isonline}} data-region="contact-icon-online">
                {{#pix}} t/go, core, {{#str}} online, message {{/str}} {{/pix}}
            </span>...
```

Then, in `\message\classes\helper.php` the code is this:

```
if (user_has_role_assignment ($userfields->id, 3)) 
{
    $data->type = "teacher";    
} else {
    $data->type = "student";        
}
```

Not enough, in `message\classes\output\messagearea\contact.php` 
in `__construct add next`:

```
$this->type = $contact->type;
```

and in `export_for_template`

```
$contact->type = $this->type;
```

So, after all I have

> next -> http://skrinshoter.ru/s/020218/5uGffk1d

Looks perfect, but when I change the tab for "contacts" I have

> nothing -> http://skrinshoter.ru/s/020218/hNZE5HUO

Any idea what can help me to show the type in contacts?

Comment: I did a major reformatting of the question. I hope that this is a real improvement.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've miss one action - clean cache in administration. After this new div block appears in contacts.